# 中 vs で for scope

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-で

Some time ago I learned about the uses of で particle and one of them is scope for example:

> このマンガは日本で有名です

but now with the uses of 中 says that when it's used after a place indicates the scope of an action in that place, so I found on internet this example:

> 英語は世界中で話されています

My question is in second sentence, What is the difference of put 中 in relation to the scope? Why not just put で? or if i put 中 in the first what does that involve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

日本で "in Japan" vs 世界中で "throughout the world". Does that help?

I think the difference here would be the emphasis that is put on the idea of *throughout*.  Pick a different language, say German or Navajo.  These two are languages spoken **in** the world, but not **throughout** the world.

Yet, in order to be famous, then such a broad scope doesn't have to be specified.  In fact, 日本で localizes where manga are well-known; elsewhere in the world, manga may not be so well known.